# cursor.execute - Using SQL function in Phython

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to call a function from SQL in Python. I am reading some values from an excel and those values have been moved in a list with json.dumps(list) .And afterword these values should be matched with the ones in SQL and retrieve accordingly other columns .

```
try: 
ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(user="x",
                                  password="y",
                                 host="z",
                                 port="w",
                                 database="w")

cursor = ps_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(select "Issuer Status" from api.match_sec_str_array("list"))

except psycopg2.OperationalError as connection_error:
print('Unable to connect to the database')
print(connection_error)

if cursor.description:
    # read the names of the columns
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
    # read the actual data
data = cursor.fetchall() 
    
cursor.close()
ps_connection.close()

pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

The error is this one :

```
Input In [15]
cursor.execute(select 'Issuer Status' from api.match_sec_str_array("list"))
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you have any idea if i missed anything ? I am also not sure if cursor.execute creates string and i have to create a query builder . Any help is much appreciated . Thanks a lot in adavance!

Comment: Your error is a basic Python `SyntaxError` which raises before _any_ code is run. Issue has nothing to do with `cursor.execute` which requires a _full_ quoted string. Your attempted query (without enclosing quotes) is not compilable by the Python interpreter even outside of any function call like `cursor.execute`: `select "Issuer Status" from api.match_sec_str_array("list")`

Answer (score 0):

In `cursor.execute()` you need to pass a string with your query. You are currently passing random keywords which are not recognized.

First, you should build your query string, and then passing to the `execute` method.

Have a look on the Psycopg docs: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

If you need to build the query string out of the result of some calls (like that `api` object) consider using the [string format method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

Comment: Hi Alhuelmo ! Thanks for help. Does not json.dumps(list) help already changing in string ?i used this when i defined the list in the beginning

Comment: I just tried this df = pd.read_excel('coverage_template.xlsx', converters={'Identifier':str}) , and stillhave the same error . Can you please suggest anything else ?Thanks a lot

Comment: How can you have the same `SyntaxError` when `read_excel` runs no SQL operations?

Comment: As @Parfait said in their question's comment, you are getting a syntax error, which is produced before any code is actually run. It's not related with the data you are trying to process, but with the code you wrote. You need to pass the proper argument (an SQL query **string**) to `execute`.